# Get missing entries in 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 MySQL tables with similar entries. I want a PHP code that will produce the entries present in one table but are not present in the other.

This the code I have .

```
SELECT date,bid,amount 
FROM finaclekenswitch 
WHERE (amount,ip) NOT IN (SELECT amount,ip FROM kenswitch)
```

It's working well but the problem is where there are look-alike entries it won't report them as missing

eg if there are `20,20,20` in one table and the other table has `20,20` the code wont report the missing `20`.

Which I also want it to do.

My table details are

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE kenswitch

CREATE TABLE kenswitch 
( 
  id int(255) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
  amount varchar(2550) NOT NULL, 
  bid varchar(2550) NOT NULL, 
  date varchar(2550) NOT NULL, 
  ip varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id) 
)

SHOW CREATE TABLE finaclekenswitch 

CREATE TABLE finaclekenswitch 
( 
  id int(255) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
  date varchar(2550) NOT NULL, 
  bid varchar(2550) NOT NULL, 
  amount varchar(2550) NOT NULL, 
  ip varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id) 
)
```

Comment: to get that (amount,ip) must be unique in both tables. Otherwise it will take all entries that fit to (amount,ip)

Comment: the problem is that some amounts are not unique

Comment: @ Gunaseelan it not working

Comment: Its getting everything its not knocking off the values

Comment: yes you answers is not what is expected can i send you the database and the expected results

Answer (score 1):

Here the simple example how select rows from one table that don't exists in another table:

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | one   |
|  2 | two   |
|  3 | three |
|  4 | four  |
|  5 | five  |
+----+-------+
SELECT * FROM table2;
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  3 | three |
|  4 | four  |
|  5 | five  |
|  6 | six   |
|  7 | seven |
+----+-------+

SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
+----+-------+------+-------+
| id | value | id   | value |
+----+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | one   | NULL | NULL  |
|  2 | two   | NULL | NULL  |
+----+-------+------+-------+
```

you should do the same...

I think your query should looks like:

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.bid, t1.amount
FROM finaclekenswitch t1
LEFT JOIN kenswitch t2 ON t1.amount = t2.amount AND t1.ip = t2.ip
WHERE t2.amount IS NULL and t2.ip IS NULL
;
```

This query will compare and amount and ip...

Comment: This is doing exactly like the one i had .

Comment: incases i have like 20,20,20,20 in amount in one table and the other table i have 20,20,20 it should print the missing 20 which its not doing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649341/get-missing-entries-in-2-tables/29650211#29650211

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from finaclekenswitch;
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | amount | ip        |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      0 | 127.0.0.0 |
|  2 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  3 |     20 | 127.0.0.2 |
|  4 |     20 | 127.0.0.3 |
|  5 |     20 | 127.0.0.4 |
+----+--------+-----------+
select * from kenswitch;
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | amount | ip        |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      0 | 127.0.0.0 |
|  2 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  3 |     20 | 127.0.0.2 |
|  4 |     20 | 127.0.0.3 |
|  5 |    200 | 127.0.0.4 |
+----+--------+-----------+
SELECT t1.*
FROM finaclekenswitch t1
LEFT JOIN kenswitch t2 ON t1.amount = t2.amount AND t1.ip = t2.ip
WHERE t2.amount IS NULL and t2.ip IS NULL
;
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | amount | ip        |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  5 |     20 | 127.0.0.4 |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

Same query without where clause, maybe it will help you:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM finaclekenswitch t1
LEFT JOIN kenswitch t2 ON t1.amount = t2.amount AND t1.ip = t2.ip
;
+----+--------+-----------+------+--------+-----------+
| id | amount | ip        | id   | amount | ip        |
+----+--------+-----------+------+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      0 | 127.0.0.0 |    1 |      0 | 127.0.0.0 |
|  2 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    2 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  3 |     20 | 127.0.0.2 |    3 |     20 | 127.0.0.2 |
|  4 |     20 | 127.0.0.3 |    4 |     20 | 127.0.0.3 |
|  5 |     20 | 127.0.0.4 | NULL |   NULL | NULL      |
+----+--------+-----------+------+--------+-----------+
```

**Another example:**

```
select * from finaclekenswitch;
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | amount | ip        |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      0 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  2 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  3 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  4 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  5 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
+----+--------+-----------+
select * from kenswitch;
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | amount | ip        |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      0 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  2 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  3 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  4 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  5 |    200 | 127.0.0.1 |
+----+--------+-----------+
SELECT t1.*
FROM finaclekenswitch t1
LEFT JOIN kenswitch t2 ON t1.amount = t2.amount AND t1.ip = t2.ip
WHERE t2.amount IS NULL and t2.ip IS NULL
;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

And it's absolutely correct result!

Let's see under the hood, same query without where clause:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM finaclekenswitch t1
LEFT JOIN kenswitch t2 ON t1.amount = t2.amount AND t1.ip = t2.ip
;
+----+--------+-----------+------+--------+-----------+
| id | amount | ip        | id   | amount | ip        |
+----+--------+-----------+------+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      0 | 127.0.0.1 |    1 |      0 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  2 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    2 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  2 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    3 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  2 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    4 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  3 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    2 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  3 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    3 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  3 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    4 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  4 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    2 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  4 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    3 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  4 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    4 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  5 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    2 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  5 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    3 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  5 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    4 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
+----+--------+-----------+------+--------+-----------+
```

If you want receive in your result row with id 5 from table finaclekenswitch, you should emphasize that you have сartesian product:

```
+----+--------+-----------+------+--------+-----------+
| id | amount | ip        | id   | amount | ip        |
+----+--------+-----------+------+--------+-----------+
|  5 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    2 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  5 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    3 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
|  5 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |    4 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |
+----+--------+-----------+------+--------+-----------+
```

and no one row satisfy condition: `WHERE t2.amount IS NULL and t2.ip IS NULL`, that's why previous result correct, because you have a row with amout 20 and ip 127.0.0.1 in both tables!

If you want to receive not just a row by amoun and ip but also by count of row in table, you might try somethink like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT amount, ip, count(*) count
    FROM finaclekenswitch
    GROUP BY amount, ip
) t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT amount, ip, count(*) count
    FROM kenswitch
    GROUP BY amount, ip
) t2 on t1.amount = t2.amount AND t1.ip = t2.ip
WHERE t1.count <> t2.count
;
+--------+-----------+-------+--------+-----------+-------+
| amount | ip        | count | amount | ip        | count |
+--------+-----------+-------+--------+-----------+-------+
|     20 | 127.0.0.1 |     4 |     20 | 127.0.0.1 |     3 |
+--------+-----------+-------+--------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: my data is posted from the same ip

Comment: Added another example, hope it will help.